# Java: Building webapp UI for sample database application

Tags: java, hibernate, web-frameworks

At university, we were given task to use ADO.NET or LINQ to SQL and build UI to show capatbilities of Microsoft tools for databases (look into Northwind, do some selecting, inserting - that requires some forms, some deleting, adding columns, transactions and so on...).

Now I'd like to bring other site to folks - show how to use Java and Hibernate. The problem is, I need to use some sort of web framework, which allows me **easily bind and manage database tables to user interface.**  Application should be some sort of visual parade of Hibernate and it's underlying DB and it should run in web browser.

I am looking from some drag and drop binging to tables, possibly wysiwyg editor, not too hard to configure. In other words, I don't want to write own components or use plain JavaScript. I'd like this stuff pre-configured.

What do you recommend to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I know of getting a database on screen with Java is using Naked Objects, currently [Apache Isis](http://incubator.apache.org/isis/index.html).

Download the tutorial to have a look, the documentation doesn't seem to friendly to people who just want to get a feeling of how the code would look.

There are plenty of other ways to get beans on a screen, like JPA, vaadin, GWT, Struts, Stripes, JSP, Velocity, Freemarker, Wicket and such. Perhaps [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/) is another candidate being a fairly easy to use templating system.

Comment: Thanks for tip, project was sadly cancelled after all :'(

Answer (score 0):

Apache Isis' domain objects are Pojos++, ie pojos plus, optionally, some annotations and following naming conventions.  Those conventions are pluggable/changeable if required, though the defaults ought to suffice for most cases.

The best Isis documentation to start with is the "applib" doc book guide; see for example http://incubator.apache.org/isis/applib/docbkx/html/guide/ch04.html.

Dan Haywood (Apache Isis committer)